# Why doesn't the AVCam sample code use layerWithSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcam

I'm trying to puzzle out the Objective-C AVCam sample code from Apple but I don't see exactly where it adds the capture session to the preview layer. Our code creates an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` pointer using the `layerWithSession` interface, but this causes a problem if we use it on the main thread, as it can take upwards of 10 seconds to finish. And what little other sample code I find on the web uses the same interface.

But I don't see that anywhere in the ObjC code for the AVCam sample. It assigns a session to the `AVCamPreviewView`, but as far as I can tell, that merely stores the object. Or does that in fact assign the session to the `UIView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the following line that ensures the PreviewView has a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer class];
}
```

layerClass() is called internally to find out what layer should be attached to this UIView when it is initialised. setSession() is then setting the session for this preview layer.